# Сделать изменяемый путь для var reader = new StreamReader(name);

Tags: winforms

Надо сделать так, чтобы при выборе 1 из 3-х вариантов в листбоксе путь для чтения файла менялся на выбранный. Данный код выдает ошибку :"System.ArgumentNullException: "Значение не может быть неопределенным. Имя параметра: path"" Сами файлы лежат в корневой папке. Пожалуйста, срочно, надо сдавать уже через 8 часов.

```
        {
            txtPhrase.Enabled = true;
            txtWrite.Enabled = true;
            Статистика.Items.Clear();
            if (index == 1)
            {
                name = "panagrams.txt";
                
            }
            if (index == 2)
            {
                name = "normal.txt";
            }
            if (index == 3)
            {
                name = "hard.txt";
            }
            
            var reader = new StreamReader(name);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    {

        if (index == 1)
        {
            name = "panagrams.txt";

        }
        else if (index == 2)
        {
            name = "normal.txt";
        }
        else
        {
            name = "hard.txt";
        }


        var reader = new StreamReader(name);
    }
```